# Firefox Add-on SDK context-menu communicate with a content script loaded by page-mod

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm creating a Firefox add-on with the Firefox Add-on SDK.  This add-on does two things:

1. Inject a content script into every page with [sdk/page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod).
2. Add a context menu item using [sdk/context-menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu).

I want that when user clicks the context menu item, the add-on will call functions in the content script which was loaded by [PageMod()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Constructors).

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: It sounds like you already have code that, at least, sets up most of what you desire. You have not included this code in your question. As such, you are setting the bar to start helping you quite high. In order to show you a tested solution someone has to re-create all the code to set up the situation. Even then, it may not duplicate the situation you have. **Please**, make it easier for people to help you and include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @Makyen thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your page-mod script is doing other things, it sounds like it might be more appropriate to load it using the [context-menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu) [`contentScript` or `contentScriptFile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu#Item%28options%29) properties. Alternately, load the portions of it that are needed by the context menu using this methodology. How best to split the script you are using depends on what you are actually doing. Without more information from you it is difficult to provide specific recommendations.

### Communicating between content scripts loaded at different times or by different methods:

There is no method of directly doing what you desire. Content scripts that are not loaded at the same time by the same methodology are loaded into different contexts. They are unable to directly call functions between them. Multiple content scripts which are loaded at the same time and the same methodology share the same context/scope and can directly call functions between them.

However, you can [communicate between content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Content_script_to_content_script). If they are *not* loaded into the same page, then you will need to communicate from one content script to another by using your main add-on script to first receive a message from one content script. Then, your main add-on script will need to send a second message (potentially containing exactly the same data) to the second content script. In other words, your main add-on code would need to relay the message between the two content scripts.

For content scripts that are loaded into the same page via different methods (e.g. one with page-mod and another as a context menu item – the situation in which you are interested), you can communicate directly between them using the [DOM postMessage() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts#Using_the_DOM_postMessage_API) or a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent).  Either can be used to send whatever JSON serializable data you desire between the two scripts. The DOM postMessage() API provides for more security, but is a bit more complex. With it you must also filter out any other `"message"` events that are sent on it by random code. It should probably be used if you are going to have code in a released add-on execute functions based on the content of the messages. This is a security issue which will depend on exactly what you are doing with the messages.

### Example:

The following code will load a page-mod script into every page that matches `"*.mozilla.org"`. It also creates a context menu item in those same pages which is displayed on links.  Clicking on the context menu item will send an event from the context-menu content script with data containing the URL for which the context menu was displayed.  The custom event will be received by the page-mod script.  The page-mod script will then issue an alert with the URL for the link.

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScript: 'function contextMenuAlert(href) {'
               + '    window.alert("The context menu click on a link with URL:\\n" + href);'
               + '};'
               + 'window.addEventListener("myAddonId-contextMenu-clicked",'
               + '    function(event){contextMenuAlert(event.detail);});'
});

//Context menu
let cm = require("sdk/context-menu");
cm.Item({
    label: "Alert link URL",
    context: [
        cm.URLContext(["*.mozilla.org"]),
        cm.SelectorContext("a[href]")
    ],
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {'
                 + '    var event = new CustomEvent("myAddonId-contextMenu-clicked",'
                 + '                                {detail:node.href});'
                 + '    window.dispatchEvent(event);'
                 + '});'
});
```

The above code produces a context menu that looks like:
[image: context menu]

When clicked on, the page-mod added content script initiates the following alert:
[image: page-mod alert]

### Using the message sent to choose from multiple different functions:

The information passed through the event can be expanded to allow multiple different functions to be called depending on the content. One method of doing this is to send an object as the message. One property of the object can be the function desired and another can be data to use in that function. My answers to the following questions contain examples of doing this:

- [Add menu item created with the sdk/context-menu API to the top of the context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770770/add-menu-item-created-with-the-sdk-context-menu-api-to-the-top-of-the-context-me/37805358#37805358): This answer has code which uses the same passed message to indicate that either a click was made on a context menu item and pass the URL on which the context menu item was clicked, or to tell the main script that the context menu is about to be displayed so it can be modified.
- [How to console.log from ChromeWorker (alternative to dump)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770770/add-menu-item-created-with-the-sdk-context-menu-api-to-the-top-of-the-context-me/37805358#37805358): This answer shows sending a message that will result in a call to one of a variety of different functions and pass data to the function which was called. It was implemented as a way of using `console` methods from a worker with just `console.log("message")`. I'd code this one a bit differently were I doing it today, but it works and demonstrates the concept.

Because the documentation on MDN ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Content_script_to_content_script) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts#Content_Scripts)) was not very clear on content script to content script communication, I have updated the pages I found on which it was discussed. I have also added the above code as an example.